# SQL syntax to get data IN date

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I have table 'salaries' with 2 timestamp field, from_date and to_date

```
no | salary | from_date     | to_date   |
------------------------------------------
1  | 30000  | 1995-12-03    | 1996-12-02 |
2  | 31000  | 1996-12-02    | 1997-12-02 |
3  | 32000  | 1997-12-02    | 1998-12-02 |
4  | 35000  | 1998-12-02    | 1999-12-02 |
5  | 37000  | 1999-12-02    | 2000-12-01 |
6  | 38000  | 2000-12-01    | 2001-12-01 |
```

I want to get salary in year 2000, so the result must be row 5 and 6. There is syntax i used:

```
SELECT * FROM salaries 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(salaries.from_date,'%Y') <= DATE_FORMAT('2000-06-20','%Y') 
AND DATE_FORMAT(salaries.to_date,'%Y') >= DATE_FORMAT('2000-06-20','%Y')


5  | 37000  | 1999-12-02    | 2000-12-01 |
6  | 38000  | 2000-12-01    | 2001-12-01 |
```

Actually the query work well; but, is there other query solutions? what query solution you suggested?

Comment: *"Actually the query work well; but, is there other query solutions? what query solution you suggested?"* Question is not really [ontopic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here it should be asked on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as the code works.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Appropriately indexed, Gordon's solution will be much more efficient than yours.

Answer (score 3):

You want overlaps of timeframes.  The correctly logic is:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM salaries s
WHERE s.from_date < '2001-01-01' AND 
      s.to_date >= '2000-01-01';
```

A salary record covers the year 2000 if it starts before the end of the year and ends after the start of the year.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM salaries
WHERE year(to_date) in (2000) and year(from_date) in (2000);
```

ref: [https://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/between-date.php][1]

Comment: This will not produce the desired result.